Deriving arc length with respect to $\theta$
I'm solving $14.19.4$ from Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. 1, and we need to show that when a curve is given by $r=f(\theta)$, its arc length is $\displaystyle\int_a^b{\sqrt{r^2 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\theta}\right)^2}\mathrm d \theta}$, where $a \le \theta \le b \le a + 2\pi$.
We know that arc length of a measurable curve is the integral of speed with respect to time $s(t) = \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t v(t) \, \mathrm dt$.
We know that in polar coordinates the speed is $ v(t) = \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2 + \left[u(t)\dfrac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dt}\right]^2}$ (note that $u$ here is just the vector norm which is usually noted as $r$, but to avoid the confusion with the $r$ defined above, I'm using $u$ to represent the vector length which depends on time $t$), so we need to show that:
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} {\sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2 + \left[u(t)\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dt}\right]^2} } dt = \int_a^b{\sqrt{r^2 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\theta}\right)^2}d \theta}. \tag{1} $$
So, to solve the problem, we just need to make the integral on the LHS in $(1)$ with respect to $\theta$.
The way I approached that is by making substitutions and putting them into $(1)$:
$$ p=\theta(t) ; \quad u(t) = q(\theta(t)) = f(p) = r $$
$$  \frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dt} = \theta'(t) \mathrm dt = \mathrm dp ; \quad \frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} = q'(\theta(t)) \theta'(t) \mathrm dt$$
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2 + \left[u(t)\dfrac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dt}\right]^2} &= \sqrt{[q'(\theta(t)) \theta'(t) \, \mathrm dt]^2 + [u(t)\theta'(t) \, \mathrm dt]^2} \\
&= \sqrt{[q'(\theta(t))]^2[\theta'(t) \, \mathrm dt]^2 + u^2(t)[\theta'(t) \, \mathrm dt]^2} \\
&= \sqrt{[\theta'(t) \, \mathrm dt]^2 \cdot [q'(\theta(t))]^2 + u^2(t)]} \\
&= |\theta'(t) \, \mathrm dt|\sqrt{[q'(\theta(t))]^2 + u^2(t)]}. \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
That means that we simplified the LHS in $(1)$ to
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} {\sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2 + \left[u(t)\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dt}\right]^2} } \mathrm dt = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}{\sqrt{[q'(\theta(t))]^2 + u^2(t)]} |\theta'(t)| \, \mathrm dt}. $$
Because $p = \theta(t), \mathrm d p = \theta'(t) \mathrm dt$, if we assume that $\theta'(t) \ge 0$, we get:
$$\int_{a}^{b}{\sqrt{[q'(p)]^2 + u^2(t)]} \, \mathrm d p} = \int_{a}^{b}{\sqrt{[f'(p)]^2 + f^2(p)]} \, \mathrm d p} \tag{3}$$
So to get to the solution, I did 2 things I'm not sure it was correct to do:

Why is it correct to assume that $\theta$ is not decreasing, so its absolute value can be removed?
Can I change $u^2(t)$ to $f^2(p)$? Is it allowed because $\theta(t)$ is continuous?

Thanks!

Can someone tell me at least why the question is down voted? :)

I've upvoted it back, but in this case $t\equiv\theta$ so (1) follows immediately... or am I missing something?

@rych Thanks for the answer! Maybe you are right, but to me it is not obvious why $t \equiv \theta$, so I would like to see your proof for that. As far as I can tell, the whole point of the exercise is to derive the arc length depending on $\theta$, by using the one which depends on $t$ (e.g. in general $\theta = g(t)$, so in general $t$ and $\theta$ are not equivalent).

TL;DR you are complicating things by including the notion of speed. Have you derived the integral for rectangular coordinates? If yes, try to convert that to polar

@DS Thanks! Your hint lead me to a simpler solution indeed.

"D S" gave me a different idea how to simplify the things, so I started with interpreting the arc length definition to be over $\theta$ domain. For that, we have to assume that the given $f$ is continuous, which implies that the arc length is also monotonically increasing with respect to $\theta$. Then we know that $s(b) = \int_a^b{v(\theta) d\theta}$, which makes the derivation of the equality needed in the exercise quite straightforward:
$\textbf{r}(\theta) = f(\theta) \cos(\theta) \textbf{i} + f(\theta)\sin(\theta)\textbf{j}$
$\textbf{r'}(\theta) = \textbf{i} \left(f'(\theta) \cos(\theta) - f(\theta) \sin(\theta) \right) + \textbf{j} \left(f'(\theta)\sin(\theta) + f(\theta)\cos(\theta)\right)$
$ \|\textbf{r}(\theta)\| = \sqrt{\left(f'(\theta) \cos(\theta) - f(\theta) \sin(\theta) \right)^2 + \left(f'(\theta)\sin(\theta) + f(\theta) \cos(\theta)\right)^2} $
$ v(\theta) = \sqrt{f'^2(\theta) + f^2(\theta)} $
$s(b) = \int_a^b{\sqrt{f'^2(\theta) + f^2(\theta)} d\theta} = \int_a^b{\sqrt{\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2 + r^2} d\theta}$
Which is the asked equality.
